# Using Tippy.js within an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, tippyjs

I'm trying to bind tooltips to some DOM elements in my component using [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/).

Below is my bare bones example `test.component.ts` as I'm unable to make it even show up.

````
import ...
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from @angular/core;
import tippy from 'tippy.js';

@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
template:
```
<div #testDiv>Hover over me.</div>
```,
styleUrls: []
})
export class TestComponent {
 @ViewChild('testDiv') testDiv: ElementRef;
 tippy(this.testDiv, { content: 'This is tooltip content.' })
}
````

Comment: The marked questions is a very custom scenario. I'm just asking how to plainly import Tippy in a component without going through a directive and all that.

Comment: This is ridiculous, so much for making SO an inclusive community!